# Erlang syntax error

Tags: erlang

When I try to compile my erlang script I keep getting this error:

```
(master@WN7-18TL6M1.amer.dell.com)15> c(distribute).
distribute.erl:55: syntax error before:
distribute.erl:42: function get_completed/3 undefined
error
```

Here is my source:

```
get_completed(Current, Index, Count) ->
    if
        length(Current) >= Index ->
            {Count, length(Current)};
        true ->
            if 
                lists:nth(Index, Current) == 'timeout' ->
                    get_completed(Current, Index+1, Count);
                true ->
                    get_completed(Current, Index+1, Count+1)
            end
    end
```

Line 55 is the last `end`

Comment: is your previous function definition ended properly with a `.`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to end the function with a period after the last end.